# Unable to load Jadira Hibernate module from web app classpath

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My web application is tightly integrated with Spring 4.3 / Hibernate 5.1.

My main `SessionFactory` object is handled by a factory that extends `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

On the `afterPropertiesSet` of the LSFB, Hibernate scans for modules and services.

I am currently getting the following error when the Jadira jar file is present in the web classpath

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:365)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:213)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:364)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:399)
    at com.acme.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 35 more
```

I am now investigating this. Looks like there is a classloader problem because of something I couldn't understand yet.

I have been digging into Spring and Hibernate code.

- `LocalSessionFactoryBean`'s `afterPropertiesSet` invokes constructor of `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` using default `MetadataSources`
- `getMetadataSources`, when invoked for the first time, builds a `BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder` using ClassLoader from `resourcePatternResolver`, which is the `WebappClassLoader` (who can look into Jars)
- When code digs into ServiceLoader class, it tries to instantiate class  `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator` using ClassLoader `org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader@70d5297f`
- The code breaks into the following line which I can't debug despite the Java sources

  ```
      try {
          c = Class.forName(cn, false, loader);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
          [OP: exception is swallowed]
          fail(service,
               "Provider " + cn + " not found");
      }
  ```

I don't understand why this happens.
Is there anything particular to do in order to load Hibernate services? How can one treat those `ServiceConfigurationError`s?

Comment: Why do you need to subclass the `FactoryBean`? What is so special that you cannot work with the default `Factorybean`?

Comment: It overrides the hibernate properties with a custom mechanism.

Comment: Why would you need that? You could simply externalize that and set the properties. I suggest trying without your subclass (using the regular `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and see if the issue is still there).

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I got the answer to my problems, it was "just" a JVM version mismatch because ServiceRegistry swallowed the root problem. Now app starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply due to Java version mismatch and the ClassNotFoundException being swallowed by ServiceRegistry.

It happens (I did not mention) that Jadira 6.x requires Java 8 / Hibernate 5.2 but I am using Java 7.

The root cause of `CNFE` is `UnsupportedClassVersionError` which can be obtained by running a simple `main` trying to instantiate the desired service class. Running the application on Java 8 helps understand this (as the error is API incompatibility with HB 5.1), so I just had to downgrade Jadira to [5.x](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.spi/5.0.0.GA)